# How do I perform the following regex match in Scala?

Tags: scala

My code is probably so butchered that I need to explain things in English.  Basically I've created a Date class and I would like it to take a String as a constructor and handle two cases

1. String in format "2011-06-30"
   get() returns "2011-06-30 00:00:00.000"
2. String in format "2011-06-30 16:32:19.452"

get() splits into rawDate=2011-06-30 and rawTime=16:32:19.452 and then prints

My attempt is below

```
case class Date(date: String) {

  // regex
  val DateAndTime = """rawDate rawTme""".r

  def get(): String = date match {
    case DateTime(rawDate, rawTime) => rawDate + "*" + rawTime
    case _ => date + " 00:00:00.000"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it does not even compile but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: It doesn't compile because you define a regexp called `DateAndTime` and you try to use `DateTime` !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val dateRegex = """([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})"""
val timeRegex = """([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3})"""
val DateOnly = dateRegex.r
val DateTime = (dateRegex + " " + timeRegex).r
def get(s:String) = s match {
  case DateTime(d,t) => d + "*" + t
  case DateOnly(d) => d + " 00:00:00.000"
}

scala> get("2011-06-30")
res1: java.lang.String = 2011-06-30 00:00:00.000

scala> get("2011-06-30 16:32:19.452")
res2: java.lang.String = 2011-06-30*16:32:19.452
```